# Vue: v-model doesn't work with dynamic components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

For example: `<component v-model='foo' :is='boo' ...>`.

`foo`'s value stays the same during input.

I'm trying to solve the issue for quite a long time. I've checked lots of questions and threads but none of those helped me.

**HTML doesn't work:**

```
            <component
                :is="field.component"
                :key="key"
                :name="field.name"
                v-for="(field, key) in integration_data"
                v-model="field.value"
            >
            </component>
```

**HTML works fine:**

```
            <input
                :key="key"
                :name="field.name"
                v-for="(field, key) in integration_data"
                v-model="field.value"
            >
```

**Vue controller:**

```
export default {
init: function (init_data) {

    return new Vue({
        data: {
            integration_data: [
              {name: 'field_name0', component: 'input', value: ''},
              {name: 'field_name0', component: 'input', value: ''},
            ]
        },
    });
}
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4763

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use `input` as a type of component and expect it to be a native input element. `:is` must name a component (which can contain an input, if you want).

Then you have to understand [how `v-model` works on components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events):

> So for a component to work with `v-model`, it should (these can be
> configured in 2.2.0+):
>
> - accept a `value` prop
> - emit an `input` event with the new value

Putting that all together, you can use `v-model` with `:is`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    integration_data: [{
      name: 'one',
      component: 'one',
      value: 'ok'
    }]
  },
  components: {
    one: {
      props: ['name', 'value'],
      template: '<div>{{name}} and <input v-model="proxyValue"><slot></slot></div>',
      computed: {
        proxyValue: {
          get() { return this.value; },
          set(newValue) { this.$emit('input', newValue); }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component 
    :is="field.component" 
    v-for="(field, key) in integration_data" 
    :key="key" 
    :name="field.name" 
    v-model="field.value"
  >
    <div>{{field.value}}</div>
  </component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand now.

Answer (score -2):

`v-model` has nothing to do with what you're possibly trying to do. It looks like you are trying to insert components dynamically. That's exactly what `:is` does. Now, to pass data to the component, you should use `props`.

For example:

Your Vue instance:

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    exampleValue: 'This value will be passed to the example component'
  }
})
```

Register a component:

```
Vue.component('example-component', {
  // declare the props
  props: ['value'],
  template: '<span>{{ value}}</span>'
})
```

Then use it like this:

```
<example-component :value="exampleValue"></example-component>
```

Or:

```
<component :is="'example-component'" :value="exampleValue"></component>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I wanted not to just to pass data to a component, but to allow the component make changes to it. On Vue's github issues it has been told that this is not possible with native elements.